# How can I tell if the node I am using is exposing the Parity trace methods?

Tags: json-rpc, nodes, ethers.js, transaction-trace, openethereum

What is the best way to tell if the node I am using is exposing the [Parity `trace` methods](https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-trace-module)?

One way I know if is to `call` a contract on Kovan and look for a revert reason that says to expose the `trace` methods, but this requires an RPC call and is not explicit (the `call` may fail for other reasons). Additionally, different clients (geth, party, etc.) return error messages, so this is not reliable. Is there a way to do this explicitly and/or without making an RPC call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try running a `trace` cURL in your terminal to the node, like:

```
curl --data '{"method":"trace_transaction","params":["0x99ac150336f74125702bb87598677c97474c5783a9258049d98377ab0773f73d"],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://green-autumn-waterfall.quiknode.pro/2ab41411fc6296f2d7f82fa096304f21968913a8/
```

If it returns a response, then it works. Otherwise it should return an explicit error, letting you know the trace module is not enabled.

Also, check the documentation of your node provider to see if they support the call or not (or ask them directly).

disclosure: work for quiknode.io

Comment: Great response. I tried that call with Quiknode, Infura, and Alchemy. The error _message_ for each was different for every one of them, and the error _code_ was the same for Infura and Alchemy (`-32601`) but different for Quiknode (`-32000`). Do  you know of a more standardized way of collecting this data without a bunch oof (`if...else`) statements?

Comment: quiknode now returns `"code":-32601` as well 

Comment: Great! Thanks for the update. Finally, I see here that there is not really a specific, defined error code for these kind of things. https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC-Error-Codes-Improvement-Proposal

Why, in this case, would you choose `-32601`? Is there a canonical list of error codes?

Comment: afaik all three providers mentioned here utilize some middle api layer, which allows for custom error messages. if one were to query a node directly, they'd see `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32601,"message":"Method not found"},"id":1}`